# Call native browser function, even after it has been overridden

Tags: javascript

If I have something like

```
alert = 0;
```

in another script.

This is in another script is and my code cannot load before that script.

How can I call the original `alert` method in my script?

Comment: if it is usefull Javascript confirm dialog can be used to show a message if the yes/no buttons can be ignored.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Before overriding the original `alert`, save it.

```
var origAlert = alert;
alert = 0;
origAlert("foo");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/tnNE7/

---

If you can't save the original value, the only other way I know of to get access to it is in an iframe.  Here's an example:

```
alert = 0;
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.height = 0;
iframe.width = 0;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
iframe.contentWindow.alert.call(window, "foo");​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/waMEV/

I haven't tried this in all browsers, but it works in Chrome, IE and Firefox and I think it should work in other browsers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I'm not overriding alert. Another script is.

Comment: And I'm running this on an existing site. My code always loads later :)

Comment: @AnkitGautam Use case: I don't want the website to know I called a function. They could modify that function from their script, so it behaves exactly like the old script, but logs somewhere that I used that function.

Comment: @Dogbert - I came up with an idea using an iframe.  See the second option I added to my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00 - ah, that's the way to a cleaner implementation of my answer - though I think stealing the method is still the better option.

Comment: I had to modify the iframe version slightly to get it to work in Firefox.  It now works in Chrome, Firefox and IE9.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I'm the first to admit this is an ugly answer, but it seems to work:

```
alert = 0;

var win = window.open(),
    method = win.alert;
win.close();

method.call(window, "my message");
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/TrseB/1/) Essentially, you make a new window instance and steal its `alert` method. The downside is that you actually have to open a new browser window, albeit briefly. I doubt this is actually a practical solution to your problem - depends what other site you're trying to work with, and how much you care about how your solution looks to the end user.

**Edit**: This is a combo of the above answer and jfriend00's answer, which solves the "open a new window" problem. I think this is a somewhat better option, as a) it doesn't rely on the iframe still being in the DOM when you need to call the method, and b) it should be generalizable to any `window` method, which jfriend00's answer probably isn't.

```
alert = 0;

// make a new window instance in an iframe
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.height = iframe.width = 0;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
// steal the method
var method = iframe.contentWindow.alert;
// remove the evidence
document.body.removeChild(iframe);

// now use the method for your own purposes
function myAlert(message) {
    method.call(window, message);
}
myAlert("foo");
```

Comment: Why are you calling `win`'s `alert` with `this` set to `window` rather than `win`?

Comment: How about stealing the fn from a newly created iframe? The result would be the same, only that you don't pop up a new window

Comment: Who knows if stealing a method from another context (window or iframe) has any possibly undesirable side effects? Will it keep anything from the unneeded context in memory, thus wasting resources? Hopefully calling with a new context (using `.bind`, `.call` or `.apply`) is good enough!