# How to get original native method if it has been overridden?

Tags: javascript, methods, overriding

Is there a way to get, for example, the original `Object.prototype.toString` method, in case it has been overridden?

Suppose some code that I have no control over does `Object.prototype.toString = function newToString() {...}`. I'd like to get the original method assuming it has already been replaced.

Is there a way?

Comment: Already been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806178/call-native-browser-function-even-after-it-has-been-overridden

Comment: Indeed, this is a duplicate! I guess I didn't search well enough.